# Neighbourhood, French railroad metric

Tags: metric-spaces

> For every two elements $x,y$ of the disk $D^2$ let
>
> $d(x,y)=\begin{cases}\|x-y\|,\text{if x and y are on the same line through (0,0)}\\ \|x\|+\|y\|, \text{else}\end{cases}$
>
> (the 'french-railroad-metric)
>
> What do the neighborhoods of $(0,0)$ and $(\frac12, 0)$ look like?

I want to figure out, what these neighborhoods look like.
For $x=(0,0)$ it is easy, because every $y\in D^2$ can be on a line through (0,0).

So $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|=\sqrt{y_1^2+y_2^2}<\varepsilon$, which means that the neighborhoods of $(0,0)$ are just circles with centre (0,0) in $D^2$.

What do the neighborhoods of $x=(\frac12,0)$ look like?

For every point on the x-axis we get $d(x,y)=\sqrt{(y_1-\frac12)^2+y_2^2}<\varepsilon$.
Which are again circles with centre $(\frac12, 0)$ on the disk.

If $y$ is not on the x-axis, we get:

$d(x,y)=\|x\|+\|y\|=\frac12+\|y\|<\varepsilon$

$\|y\|<\varepsilon-\frac12$.

Which are circles with centre (0,0) and a maximal radius of $1/2$?

So for $\varepsilon=1$ for example, we would get this picture? (The red colored area)

[image]

Thanks in advance, for your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you wouldn't get that red-shaded area. The ball around $(\frac12,0)$ of radius $1$ looks like

[image: Figure 1]

But that doesn't do a very good job of showing what's going on. We need a smaller ball for that. Here's the ball of radius $\frac14$ centered at $(\frac12,0)$, at the same scale:

[image: Figure 2]

If the radius is small enough that you can't reach Paris, you're stuck on the line you started on.

Comment: How do you get this red line? What have I done wrong? What I understand is, that if the condition $\|y\|<\varepsilon-\frac12$ 'fails', which means we get something negativ on the RHS (for $\varepsilon=1/4$) we do not get a circle around (0,0). Why does the metric for points on the x-axis not give circles, but a straight line?

Comment: There are two cases in that distance function. The red line comes from the first case - staying on the same line. And if the radius is shorter than the distance to the origin, staying on that line is the only option.

Comment: Thank you. I see my mistake now. I had to set $y_2=0$ in my calculation, which then just gives a real number: $|y_1-\frac12|$. Then it is clear, that we get this straight line and not cirlces!