# Sketch the open balls for the Railway Metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, open-map

Hi I'm having trouble picturing the open balls for the Railway metric

```
 (,)={2(,) if ,,0 are collinear

         2(,0)+2(0,) otherwise
```

I need to sketch the open balls of Bd(0,1), Bd((1,0),1) and Bd((1/2,0),1)

I have seen pictures of them like a "lollipop" but don't know how to show for these cases.

Comment: You might find this helpful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3094473/neighbourhood-french-railroad-metric

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The name "Railway Metric" comes from the following image. Suppose there are a number of railway lines which start at the origin $O$ and go radially outwards in straight lines. From a station $A$ on line $OA$ you can travel directly to any other point on the line $OA$ towards $O$ or away from $O$, but to reach a station on another line you have travel in to $O$, change to the other line, and then travel back out again.

This gives you a useful intuitive picture of how this metric behaves.

To picture the open ball with radius $1$ around $O$ ask yourself the following question "what places can I travel to in less than $1$ hour by train if I start at $O$ ?".

To picture the open ball with radius $1$ around $(1,0)$ ask yourself the following question "what places can I travel to in less than $1$ hour if I start at $A$ which is $1$ hour by train from $O$ ?".

To picture the open ball with radius $1$ around $(\frac 1 2,0)$ ask yourself the following question "what places can I travel to in less than $1$ hour if I start at $B$ which is $\frac 1 2$ hour by train from $O$ ?".

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly the kind of explanation I was looking for!

Comment: could i confirm my answers now with you. For Bd(0,1) I would have a circle around the origin, radius 1. 
For Bd((1,0),1) I would have a Line from 1 to the origin and a ball around the origin (is the radius of this ball now 1/2?)
For Bd((1/2,0),1) would this also be a ball and line, this time values wrt (1/2,0)

Comment: @mathsstudent101 For $Bd((1,0),1)$ and $Bd((\frac 1 2,0),1)$ don't forget that you can travel away from the origin as well as towards it.

Comment: But if you travel away too, taking (1,0) as eg you would not be within the hour train from O?

Comment: @mathsstudent101 $Bd((1,0),1)$ is the open ball of radius $1$ around $(1,0)$ - so in the train analogy you can travel up to 1 hour starting from $(1,0)$, not starting from the origin.